# Cannot save record using Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, winforms, frameworks, entity

Can someone help?

I am an absolute beginner. But I searched the net. There are not many example shown in VB anywhere.

I have created a test project which holds the win form. Then added another project which holds the Entity Model, after building the Model I added a reference of this to the Win form project. After that I added the Model object as a datasource.

I dragged the datasource controls into the form and added the below code.

```
Private context As TestModelEntities

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    context = New TestModelEntities

    Dim query = context.employees
    EmployeeBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList




End Sub

Private Sub DepartmentBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles EmployeeBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click



    Try
        context.SaveChanges()
        MessageBox.Show("Changes saved to the database.")
        Me.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I am scratching my head all day. Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your `DepartmentBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click` method, it appears that you are not adding anything to the `context` prior to calling `context.SaveChanges()`.

Thus, Entity Framework does not know about any newly-added entities and is not persisting them.

Try adding your entities to context and then calling `context.SaveChanges()`.

**UPDATE**

Here is an MSDN Article on Adding/Attaching Entities to the Context: [Entity Framework Add/Attach and Entity States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

Unfortunately it's in C# (I couldn't find a translation or equivalent article in VB.NET), but the idea is the same for adding or attaching `Employee` (or `Department`) to your context prior to `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Thanks Philip,My understanding was that it is one the benefit of using the entity framework. It maps the the text boxes to the database fields. I may be wrong. But I followed the MSDN example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff706685.aspx.

Comment: @Anup I haven't used EF with Windows Forms (I've used it with ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC).  At the end of the day, even if you find a way to bind a textbox to an entity field, you still need to add it to the context before calling SaveChanges, otherwise there are no changes to save.  I would start with a simple example, new up an Employee (or whatever entity object you are using), add it to the Context, and call SaveChanges and verify it persisted.

Comment: Do you mean I have to write someting like, context.table.field=AutoGeneratedTextBoxes.text for every field?

Comment: @Anup I think you're getting too hung up on WinForms and trying to use databind to Entities (which I have not done).  I would recommend you just create a simple ASP.NET web page with a button that does nothing but construct and save (with hardcoded values) an Entity.  From there, you could work on making it dynamic, going to WinForms, etc.

Comment: Can anyone help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about your question, but I may have some tips that can help. First off, as @Philip Tenn stated, you'll need to add whatever it is your creating to the context. It's really easy in vb.net, just write:

Context.Table.Add(Object2Add).

That will put the object in that data table. Now when you query you should say something like:

Dim MyQuery as IEnumerable(of DataTable) = (From a in Context.DataTable).ToList.

This will get everything from that data table and store it in a list. One problem that you might have with your code is that context needs to be declared inside each sub seperately (so Dim Context as new TestModelEntity) or globally (so Public Context as new testModelEntity  (this is outside of your subs)). I know I'm a few years late but hopefully this helps someone!